# Unable to save Excel file with macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macros which works perfectly on a Word document, but crashes when I try to use it in Excel. This macros saves currently opened file, using PHP file. PHP file analyzes the full name of the document and uploads it to a particular folder. The code looks like this:

**VB**

```
Const BaseUrl = "http://localhost/docxgen-master/upload.php"

Sub SaveCopyAs(SaveAsPath)
    Const lCancelled_c As Long = 0  
    If VBA.LenB(SaveAsPath) = lCancelled_c Then Exit Sub
    ActiveDocument.Save
    Application.Documents.Add ActiveDocument.FullName
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs SaveAsPath, wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
    ActiveDocument.Close
End Sub

Sub Macros1()
    FileName = ActiveDocument.FullName + "temp"    
    SaveCopyAs FileName   
    MsgBox WinHTTPPostRequest(BaseUrl, FileName, ActiveDocument.Name)
End Sub

'Other subroutines like WinHTTPPostRequest etc
```

**PHP**: upload.php

```
$fileInfo = current($_FILES);
if (!$fileInfo) die;
$target_path = "./templates/";
$pattern = '|_\d+|';
preg_match_all($pattern,$fileInfo['name'], $matches);
$target_path =  $target_path."report_0".$matches[0][1].$matches[0][2].$matches[0][3].".docm";   
if(!move_uploaded_file($fileInfo['tmp_name'], $target_path)) die;
echo "You saved it!";
```

This code works perfectly fine, if it is used in a doc file. I tried to use it in Excel, but to no avail. Of course, I made some minor corrections to the code:

```
Sub SaveCopyAs(SaveAsPath)
    Const lCancelled_c As Long = 0  
    If VBA.LenB(SaveAsPath) = lCancelled_c Then Exit Sub
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.Workbooks.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SaveAsPath, wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Still, it does not work.

**EDIT**

Now, my code looks like this:

```
Sub SaveCopyAs(SaveAsPath)
    Const lCancelled_c As Long = 0
    If VBA.LenB(SaveAsPath) = lCancelled_c Then Exit Sub
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SaveAsPath, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

And now it almost works! It saves the document, but unfortunately without macros.

**EDIT**

My final version of code looks like this:

```
Sub SaveCopyAs(SaveAsPath)
    Const lCancelled_c As Long = 0
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Workbooks.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SaveAsPath, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

But the debugger throws an error, pointing to `ActiveWorkbook.Save` (error message is in Russian, so I do not know the correct interpretation, but it is about VB and macros)

**EDIT**

This is GetFile function which raises an error when I try a simplified code of saving the document:

```
Function GetFile(FileName)
  Dim Stream: Set Stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  Stream.Type = 1 'Binary
  Stream.Open
  Stream.LoadFromFile FileName ' The debugger points to this line now (firts test case of code)
  GetFile = Stream.Read
  Stream.Close
End Function
```

Comment: You forgot to change the fileformat parameter to the Excel equivalent: `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` rather than `wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled`

Comment: I fixed it, but it still does not work.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than just "does not work" please.

Comment: I updated my question. At this point I'm able to save document, but unable to save it with vb code (macros etc.)

Comment: You saved a new blank workbook (`Workbooks.Add`), hence no macros. Why don't you just use `SaveAs` instead of add a new blank workbook?

Comment: That code wouldn't run since there is no `SaveCopy` method. You need `SaveAs`, or `SaveCopyAs` without adding a new workbook and without specifying the file format (you can't change file format if you use this method).

Comment: Thanks! If you provide a full code, I will check it and mark as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you either use this:

```
Sub SaveCopyAs(SaveAsPath)
    Const lCancelled_c As Long = 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SaveAsPath, xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub SaveCopyAs(SaveAsPath)
    Const lCancelled_c As Long = 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs SaveAsPath
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

The latter will not allow you to change file format.

Comment: Thanks for all efforts. Unfortunatelly, I get run time errors, when I test your code.

Comment: Please be *specific* as to what errors and on which lines.

Comment: Firts version results in an alert, that file already exists and asks to replace, if I hit "Yes", then I see run time error '3002': Unable to open the file, if I then hit "Debug", the debugger points to this line of code: `Stream.LoadFromFile FileName` inside my GetFile function.

Comment: I used this GetFile function in a Word document. As far as I can see, in this function there is nothing specific to word or excel.

Comment: Well according to my crystal ball, it's probably line 8 of the function you haven't posted that's causing the problem. Or maybe you just need to close it in the code above. Or perhaps it's the fact you have "docm" in your upload.php. Or...

Comment: -) I see what you mean. I will post GetFile function right now.